# mco puppet configuration issues

Tags: puppet, mcollective

I am facing some while configuring `mcollective` for `puppet`

```
# mco puppet runonce
The Marionette Collective version 2.8.8

 Unknown command 'puppet', searched for applications in:


/usr/libexec/mcollective
/usr/share/mcollective/plugins
/opt/puppetlabs/mcollective/plugins
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/stomp-1.3.3/lib
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.1.0
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mcollective/vendor/systemu/lib
```

It is showing `Puppet command not found` . `mco ping` is working fine

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved after installing the following packages

```
sudo yum install mcollective-puppet-agent
sudo yum install mcollective-service-agent
sudo yum install mcollective-puppet-client

/opt/puppetlabs/bin/mco puppet help

The puppet application failed to run, use -v for full error backtrace    
details: Action must be count, enable, disable, resource, runall,  
runonce, status or summary
```